# AspNetCore giving 404 when trying to use Action Parameter

Tags: asp.net-core

I have an action:

```
public class CalculatorController : Controller
{   
    public IActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        return Content($"Value: {id}");
    }
}
```

I have a route mapped in Startup.cs

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "calculator",
    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

If I go to:
`/calculator/` I get "Value: 0"

If I go to:
`/calculator/123` I get 404 Page Not Found

If I go to:
`/calculator/?id=123` I get "Value: 123"

I've tried adding another route just for Calculator controller too see if that made a difference:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "calculator",
    template: "{controller=Calculator}/{action=Index}/{id}");
```

But still get 404 when I visit /calculator/123

How can I get my url's to work directly without needing to use a querystring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, 5 min after I post the question I facepalm as i realise the answer

I should be going to `/calculatore/index/123`

`/calculator/123` would be looking for an Action called 123

`/calculator/id=123` works because it's specifying the 123 as Id, so it knows to default the missing action-name to Index as per what's defined in the MapRoute

Thanks guys

Comment: Please consider answer accepting to avoid other's facepalms =)

Comment: Will do, but it's still telling me I have to wait before I can accept